# Quiz inside collapsible navigation drawer

Tags: android

Im trying to add a radio button option on my collapsible navigation drawer, my motive here is to create a quiz for the lessons that I have. However, In my case 
statements, its not accepting activity

xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question Here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 3" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClear"
            android:text="Clear " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onSubmit"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

java

```
    package com.android.pet.view;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer.R;

    public class Lesson111 extends Activity {
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onepointthree);

        /* Initialize Radio Group and attach click handler */
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.clearCheck();

        /* Attach CheckedChangeListener to radio group */
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
                if(null!=rb && checkedId > -1){
                    Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void onClear(View v) {
        /* Clears all selected radio buttons to default */
        radioGroup.clearCheck();
    }

    public void onSubmit(View v) {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

main activity java

```
    package com.android.pet.view;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer.R;

    public class NavigationActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ImageView home;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    TextView appname;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    List<String> listDataHeader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String fontPath = "fonts/Shadow Boxing.ttf";
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        home = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home);
        home.setOnClickListener(homeOnclickListener);
        appname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.appname);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), fontPath);
        appname.setTypeface(tf);
        setUpDrawer();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Get the names and icons references to build the drawer menu...
     */
    private void setUpDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        fragment = new Lesson1();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new Lesson1();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new Lesson11();
                        break;
```

now Im having a problem here, Since its not accepting an activity. If i change the fragment = new Lesson111(); to activity = new Lesson111(); . The Activity will turn red and says cannot resolve symbol activity. Is there any way to fix this?

```
            case 2:
                fragment = new Lesson111();
                break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
```

continuation of the main activity java

```
                    case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new Lesson2();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new Lesson22();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new Lesson222();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new Lesson3();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new Lesson33();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new Lesson333();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                    case 3:
                        switch (childPosition) {
                            case 0:
                                fragment = new Lesson4();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                fragment = new Lesson44();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                fragment = new Lesson444();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        switch (childPosition) {
                            case 0:
                                fragment = new Lesson5();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                fragment = new Lesson55();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                fragment = new Lesson555();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;


                    default:
                    break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    View.OnClickListener homeOnclickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(expListView)){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
            }else{
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(expListView);
            }
        }
    };

    private OnItemClickListener mDrawerItemClickedListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            switch(position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new Lesson1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Lesson2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Lesson3();
                break;

                case 3:
                    fragment = new Lesson4();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = new Lesson5();
                    break;

            default:
                return;
            }

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
        }
    };

    // Catch the events related to the drawer to arrange views according to this
    // action if necessary...
    private DrawerListener mDrawerListener = new DrawerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int status) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideArg) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        }
    };

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Lesson 1");
        listDataHeader.add("Lesson 2");
        listDataHeader.add("Lesson 3");
        listDataHeader.add("Lesson 4");
        listDataHeader.add("Lesson 5");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> Lesson1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Lesson1.add("Objectives");
        Lesson1.add("Contents");
        Lesson1.add("Quiz");

        List<String> Lesson2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Lesson2.add("Objectives");
        Lesson2.add("Contents");
        Lesson2.add("Quiz");


        List<String> Lesson3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Lesson3.add("Objectives");
        Lesson3.add("Contents");
        Lesson3.add("Quiz");


        List<String> Lesson4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Lesson4.add("Objectives");
        Lesson4.add("Contents");
        Lesson4.add("Quiz");

        List<String> Lesson5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Lesson5.add("Objectives");
        Lesson5.add("Contents");
        Lesson5.add("Quiz");


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Lesson1); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Lesson2);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Lesson3);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), Lesson4);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), Lesson5);
    }

    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share some code?

Comment: @CAMOBAP Hi, I already uploaded the code.